# How make a click in button with windows AutomationElement

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automation, automated-tests

Following this article 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141842/Automate-your-UI-using-Microsoft-Automation-Framew

I'm trying to open an application and press a button. This is all that I want.

```
public RecordProgram()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\MouseController.exe", @"C:\test1.mcd");
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        _calculatorProcess = Process.Start(psi);

        int ct = 0;
        do
        {
            _calculatorAutomationElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "MouseController (1,0x)"));
            ++ct;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        } 
        while (_calculatorAutomationElement == null && ct < 50);

        if (_calculatorAutomationElement == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Calculator must be running");
        }

        _resultTextBoxAutomationElement = _calculatorAutomationElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Element, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "920388"));

        if (_resultTextBoxAutomationElement == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find result box");
        }

        GetInvokePattern(GetFunctionButton(Functions.Clear)).Invoke();
    }
```

The prograns run and open the executable with my file load But _resultTextBoxAutomationElement returns null value.

```
_resultTextBoxAutomationElement = _calculatorAutomationElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Element, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "920388"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the call to _calculatorAutomationElement.FindFirst() be passing in TreeScope.Children instead of TreeScope.Element? (Assuming the button element you're after is a direct child of the app window element.) By passing in TreeScope.Element as you are doing, UIA will only look at the _calculatorAutomationElement itself for an element with an AutomationId of 920388.

Thanks,

Guy

Comment: not work with TreeScope.Childer neither TreeScope.Descendants

Comment: You're looking for an element whose AutomationId property is 920388. Where is that number coming from? If I point the Inspect SDK tool to the Win32 Run dialog, I can see the Browse button in the dialog has an AutomationId of 12288. If I then point the Spy tool to the same button, I see it has a Control ID of 0x3000, (ie 12288). So the Win32 UI framework is automatically exposing the Control ID as the UIA AutomationId. Given that your image above shows the Control ID as 0x23094A, what happens if you look for an element with an AutomationId of 2296138?

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate my comment above which mentioned the Run dlg's Browse button as an example of accessing a Win32 button through its AutomationId, I've just written the code below to access the Browse button. The code is using a managed wrapper around the Windows UIA API, that I'd generated using the tlbimp.exe tool, but I expect taking a similar approach with the .NET UIA API would work fine too.

So for the MouseController UI shown above, try changing the line to...

```
_resultTextBoxAutomationElement = _calculatorAutomationElement.FindFirst(
    TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition
        (AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "2296138"));
```

(I'm assuming that the Inspect SDK tool does show the AutomationId of the "start playback" button is "2296138".)

Thanks,

Guy

```
IUIAutomation uiAutomation = new CUIAutomation();

IUIAutomationElement rootElement = uiAutomation.GetRootElement();

int propertyIdName = 30005; // UIA_NamePropertyId

// First find the Run dlg, which is a direct child of the root element.
// For this test, assume there's only one element whose title is "Run"
// beneath the root. Note! This only works in English UI.
IUIAutomationCondition conditionName =
    uiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(
        propertyIdName, "Run");

IUIAutomationElement wndElement = rootElement.FindFirst(
    TreeScope.TreeScope_Children, conditionName);
if (wndElement != null)
{
    // Ok, we have the Run dialog. Now find the Browse button through its AutomationId.
    int propertyAutomationId = 30011; // UIA_AutomationIdPropertyId

    // Using the Inspect SDK tool, I could see that the AutomationId of
    // the Browse button is "12288".
    IUIAutomationCondition conditionAutomationId =
        uiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(
            propertyAutomationId, "12288");

    // Get the name of the button cached when we find the button, so that 
    // we don't have to make a cross-process call later to get the name.
    IUIAutomationCacheRequest cacheRequestName = uiAutomation.CreateCacheRequest();
    cacheRequestName.AddProperty(propertyIdName);

    IUIAutomationElement btnElement = wndElement.FindFirstBuildCache(
        TreeScope.TreeScope_Children, conditionAutomationId, cacheRequestName);
    if (btnElement != null)
    {
        // Let's see the name now...
        MessageBox.Show(btnElement.CachedName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where I can found the reference for IUIAutomation ?

Comment: Details on IUIAutomation can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671406(v=vs.85).aspx. Details on other client interfaces for the Windows UIA API are at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671215(v=vs.85).aspx.